# How to send keypresses from qt application to libvlc

Tags: qt, vlc, libvlc

I need to send keypresses from my application window to libvlc, how do I do that? I tried using varSetInteger but then I got the following error:

```
error: ‘var_SetInteger’ was not declared in this scope
```

so I searched for the file in which var_SetInteger was defined and found that it was defined in vlc_variables.h so in included it and got the following error. What am I missing?

```
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:121: error: ‘__var_Create’ has not been declared
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:121: error: expected identifier before ‘(’ token
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:121: error: expected `)' before ‘*’ token
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:121: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘*’ token
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:121: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘)’ token
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:122: error: ‘__var_Destroy’ has not been declared
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:122: error: expected identifier before ‘(’ token
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:122: error: expected `)' before ‘*’ token
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:122: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘*’ token
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:122: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘)’ token
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:124: error: ‘__var_Change’ has not been declared
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:124: error: expected identifier before ‘(’ token
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:124: error: expected `)' before ‘*’ token
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:124: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘*’ token
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:124: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘)’ token
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:126: error: ‘__var_Type’ has not been declared
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:126: error: expected identifier before ‘(’ token
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:126: error: expected `)' before ‘*’ token
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:126: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘*’ token
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:126: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘)’ token
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:127: error: ‘__var_Set’ has not been declared
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:127: error: expected identifier before ‘(’ token
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:127: error: expected `)' before ‘*’ token
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:127: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘*’ token
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:127: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘)’ token
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:128: error: ‘__var_Get’ has not been declared
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:128: error: expected identifier before ‘(’ token
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:128: error: expected `)' before ‘*’ token
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:128: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘*’ token
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:128: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘)’ token
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:131: error: ‘__var_Command’ has not been declared
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:131: error: expected identifier before ‘(’ token
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:131: error: expected `)' before ‘*’ token
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:131: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘*’ token
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:131: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘)’ token
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:133: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:171: error: ‘__var_AddCallback’ has not been declared
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:171: error: expected identifier before ‘(’ token
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:171: error: expected `)' before ‘*’ token
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:171: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘*’ token
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:171: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘)’ token
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:172: error: ‘__var_DelCallback’ has not been declared
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:172: error: expected identifier before ‘(’ token
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:172: error: expected `)' before ‘*’ token
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:172: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘*’ token
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:172: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘)’ token
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:173: error: ‘__var_TriggerCallback’ has not been declared
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:173: error: expected identifier before ‘(’ token
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:173: error: expected `)' before ‘*’ token
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:173: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘*’ token
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:173: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘)’ token
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:201: error: ‘__var_SetInteger’ declared as an ‘inline’ variable
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:201: error: ‘vlc_object_t’ was not declared in this scope
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:201: error: ‘p_obj’ was not declared in this scope
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:201: error: expected primary-expression before ‘const’
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:201: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:201: error: initializer expression list treated as compound expression
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:202: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:215: error: ‘__var_SetBool’ declared as an ‘inline’ variable
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:215: error: ‘vlc_object_t’ was not declared in this scope
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:215: error: ‘p_obj’ was not declared in this scope
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:215: error: expected primary-expression before ‘const’
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:215: error: expected primary-expression before ‘bool’
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:215: error: initializer expression list treated as compound expression
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:216: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:229: error: ‘__var_SetTime’ declared as an ‘inline’ variable
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:229: error: ‘vlc_object_t’ was not declared in this scope
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:229: error: ‘p_obj’ was not declared in this scope
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:229: error: expected primary-expression before ‘const’
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:229: error: expected primary-expression before ‘i’
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:229: error: initializer expression list treated as compound expression
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:230: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:243: error: ‘__var_SetFloat’ declared as an ‘inline’ variable
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:243: error: ‘vlc_object_t’ was not declared in this scope
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:243: error: ‘p_obj’ was not declared in this scope
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:243: error: expected primary-expression before ‘const’
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:243: error: expected primary-expression before ‘float’
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:243: error: initializer expression list treated as compound expression
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:244: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:257: error: ‘__var_SetString’ declared as an ‘inline’ variable
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:257: error: ‘vlc_object_t’ was not declared in this scope
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:257: error: ‘p_obj’ was not declared in this scope
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:257: error: expected primary-expression before ‘const’
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:257: error: expected primary-expression before ‘const’
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:257: error: initializer expression list treated as compound expression
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:258: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:270: error: ‘__var_SetVoid’ declared as an ‘inline’ variable
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:270: error: ‘vlc_object_t’ was not declared in this scope
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:270: error: ‘p_obj’ was not declared in this scope
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:270: error: expected primary-expression before ‘const’
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:270: error: initializer expression list treated as compound expression
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:271: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:302: error: ‘__var_GetInteger’ declared as an ‘inline’ variable
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:302: error: ‘vlc_object_t’ was not declared in this scope
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:302: error: ‘p_obj’ was not declared in this scope
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:302: error: expected primary-expression before ‘const’
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:302: error: initializer expression list treated as compound expression
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:303: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:317: error: ‘__var_GetBool’ declared as an ‘inline’ variable
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:317: error: ‘vlc_object_t’ was not declared in this scope
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:317: error: ‘p_obj’ was not declared in this scope
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:317: error: expected primary-expression before ‘const’
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:317: error: initializer expression list treated as compound expression
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:318: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:332: error: ‘__var_GetTime’ declared as an ‘inline’ variable
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:332: error: ‘vlc_object_t’ was not declared in this scope
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:332: error: ‘p_obj’ was not declared in this scope
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:332: error: expected primary-expression before ‘const’
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:332: error: initializer expression list treated as compound expression
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:333: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:347: error: ‘__var_GetFloat’ declared as an ‘inline’ variable
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:347: error: ‘vlc_object_t’ was not declared in this scope
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:347: error: ‘p_obj’ was not declared in this scope
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:347: error: expected primary-expression before ‘const’
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:347: error: initializer expression list treated as compound expression
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:348: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:362: error: ‘__var_GetString’ declared as an ‘inline’ variable
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:362: error: ‘vlc_object_t’ was not declared in this scope
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:362: error: ‘p_obj’ was not declared in this scope
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:362: error: expected primary-expression before ‘const’
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:362: error: initializer expression list treated as compound expression
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:363: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:371: error: ‘__var_GetNonEmptyString’ declared as an ‘inline’ variable
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:371: error: ‘vlc_object_t’ was not declared in this scope
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:371: error: ‘obj’ was not declared in this scope
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:371: error: expected primary-expression before ‘const’
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:371: error: initializer expression list treated as compound expression
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:372: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:412: error: variable or field ‘__var_IncInteger’ declared void
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:412: error: ‘vlc_object_t’ was not declared in this scope
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:412: error: ‘p_obj’ was not declared in this scope
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:412: error: expected primary-expression before ‘const’
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:424: error: variable or field ‘__var_DecInteger’ declared void
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:424: error: ‘vlc_object_t’ was not declared in this scope
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:424: error: ‘p_obj’ was not declared in this scope
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:424: error: expected primary-expression before ‘const’
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:437: error: ‘__var_CreateGetInteger’ declared as an ‘inline’ variable
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:437: error: ‘vlc_object_t’ was not declared in this scope
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:437: error: ‘p_obj’ was not declared in this scope
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:437: error: expected primary-expression before ‘const’
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:437: error: initializer expression list treated as compound expression
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:438: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:449: error: ‘__var_CreateGetBool’ declared as an ‘inline’ variable
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:449: error: ‘vlc_object_t’ was not declared in this scope
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:449: error: ‘p_obj’ was not declared in this scope
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:449: error: expected primary-expression before ‘const’
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:449: error: initializer expression list treated as compound expression
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:450: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:461: error: ‘__var_CreateGetTime’ declared as an ‘inline’ variable
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:461: error: ‘vlc_object_t’ was not declared in this scope
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:461: error: ‘p_obj’ was not declared in this scope
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:461: error: expected primary-expression before ‘const’
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:461: error: initializer expression list treated as compound expression
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:462: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:473: error: ‘__var_CreateGetFloat’ declared as an ‘inline’ variable
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:473: error: ‘vlc_object_t’ was not declared in this scope
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:473: error: ‘p_obj’ was not declared in this scope
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:473: error: expected primary-expression before ‘const’
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:473: error: initializer expression list treated as compound expression
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:474: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:485: error: ‘__var_CreateGetString’ declared as an ‘inline’ variable
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:485: error: ‘vlc_object_t’ was not declared in this scope
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:485: error: ‘p_obj’ was not declared in this scope
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:486: error: expected primary-expression before ‘const’
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:486: error: initializer expression list treated as compound expression
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:487: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:492: error: ‘__var_CreateGetNonEmptyString’ declared as an ‘inline’ variable
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:492: error: ‘vlc_object_t’ was not declared in this scope
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:492: error: ‘p_obj’ was not declared in this scope
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:493: error: expected primary-expression before ‘const’
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:493: error: initializer expression list treated as compound expression
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:494: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:527: error: ‘__var_CreateGetIntegerCommand’ declared as an ‘inline’ variable
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:527: error: ‘vlc_object_t’ was not declared in this scope
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:527: error: ‘p_obj’ was not declared in this scope
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:527: error: expected primary-expression before ‘const’
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:527: error: initializer expression list treated as compound expression
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:528: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:540: error: ‘__var_CreateGetBoolCommand’ declared as an ‘inline’ variable
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:540: error: ‘vlc_object_t’ was not declared in this scope
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:540: error: ‘p_obj’ was not declared in this scope
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:540: error: expected primary-expression before ‘const’
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:540: error: initializer expression list treated as compound expression
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:541: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:553: error: ‘__var_CreateGetTimeCommand’ declared as an ‘inline’ variable
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:553: error: ‘vlc_object_t’ was not declared in this scope
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:553: error: ‘p_obj’ was not declared in this scope
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:553: error: expected primary-expression before ‘const’
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:553: error: initializer expression list treated as compound expression
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:554: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:566: error: ‘__var_CreateGetFloatCommand’ declared as an ‘inline’ variable
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:566: error: ‘vlc_object_t’ was not declared in this scope
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:566: error: ‘p_obj’ was not declared in this scope
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:566: error: expected primary-expression before ‘const’
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:566: error: initializer expression list treated as compound expression
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:567: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:579: error: ‘__var_CreateGetStringCommand’ declared as an ‘inline’ variable
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:579: error: ‘vlc_object_t’ was not declared in this scope
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:579: error: ‘p_obj’ was not declared in this scope
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:580: error: expected primary-expression before ‘const’
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:580: error: initializer expression list treated as compound expression
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:581: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:587: error: ‘__var_CreateGetNonEmptyStringCommand’ declared as an ‘inline’ variable
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:587: error: ‘vlc_object_t’ was not declared in this scope
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:587: error: ‘p_obj’ was not declared in this scope
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:588: error: expected primary-expression before ‘const’
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:588: error: initializer expression list treated as compound expression
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:589: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
src/transcribeWidget.cpp:859: warning: unused parameter ‘bytesSent’
src/transcribeWidget.cpp:859: warning: unused parameter ‘bytesTotal’
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:201: warning: ‘__var_SetInteger’ defined but not used
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:215: warning: ‘__var_SetBool’ defined but not used
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:229: warning: ‘__var_SetTime’ defined but not used
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:243: warning: ‘__var_SetFloat’ defined but not used
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:257: warning: ‘__var_SetString’ defined but not used
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:270: warning: ‘__var_SetVoid’ defined but not used
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:302: warning: ‘__var_GetInteger’ defined but not used
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:317: warning: ‘__var_GetBool’ defined but not used
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:332: warning: ‘__var_GetTime’ defined but not used
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:347: warning: ‘__var_GetFloat’ defined but not used
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:362: warning: ‘__var_GetString’ defined but not used
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:371: warning: ‘__var_GetNonEmptyString’ defined but not used
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:437: warning: ‘__var_CreateGetInteger’ defined but not used
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:449: warning: ‘__var_CreateGetBool’ defined but not used
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:461: warning: ‘__var_CreateGetTime’ defined but not used
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:473: warning: ‘__var_CreateGetFloat’ defined but not used
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:485: warning: ‘__var_CreateGetString’ defined but not used
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:492: warning: ‘__var_CreateGetNonEmptyString’ defined but not used
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:527: warning: ‘__var_CreateGetIntegerCommand’ defined but not used
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:540: warning: ‘__var_CreateGetBoolCommand’ defined but not used
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:553: warning: ‘__var_CreateGetTimeCommand’ defined but not used
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:566: warning: ‘__var_CreateGetFloatCommand’ defined but not used
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:579: warning: ‘__var_CreateGetStringCommand’ defined but not used
../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h:587: warning: ‘__var_CreateGetNonEmptyStringCommand’ defined but not used
```

Comment: You need to provide more information.  Why are you trying to send key presses to libvlc?  If you want to perform some function you should call that function directly instead of trying to pass key events.

Answer (score 0):

Did you just include it directly as "../vlc-0.9.10/include/vlc_variables.h" and do nothing else?

If so then you'll need to add `/path/to/vlc-0.9.10/include` to your compilation command so that it can find all the vlc headers. That's because vlc_variables.h will no doubt include other vlc headers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need add

```
# ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
# endif
```